# Windows Forms checkbox changed vs updated?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible in C# Windows Forms to differentiate between a `checkbox` being toggled via a click by the user and an update to it originating from another event?

I have a `listbox` of values and a panel of `checkboxes` containing yes/no information about the items in the listbox. When an item in the listbox is selected, I want to update the `checkboxes` with its information. The complication comes in where one of the `checkboxes` represents a unique status, something that only one of the items in the `listbox` is allowed to have. If the user clicks on that `checkbox` when it is in the unchecked state I want it to set the field true for the currently selected item and false for whichever item previously held it true.

As I understand it, the `CheckedChanged` event will fire on both the `listbox` selection change (setting the `checkbox` values for that item) AND on the user click. I need a way to split them out.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you explain more why do you need to split them out? For example would having two events one on `CheckedChanged` and one on `Click` be acceptable? Or does your data source you bound the checkbox to expose a event that fires on change that you could subscribe to instead to tell the difference?

Comment: Clarify:  is this a `CheckedListBox` or a discrete `Checkbox`.  They are _not_ the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand it, the CheckedChanged event will fire on both the
>   listbox selection change (setting the checkbox values for that item)
>   AND on the user click. I need a way to split them out.

Yes, you are right, the `CheckedChanged` event will be raised when you update the `checkBox` state (that you do when `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event or something like this is raised I guess).

What you need is to disable the handler before you update the `CheckBox` state.

```
private void myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //disable checkbox event
    mycheckbox.CheckedChanged -= mycheckbox_CheckedChanged;

    //you can change the checkbox state here
    //...

    //Activate event
    mycheckbox.CheckedChanged += myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void mycheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //(...)
}
```

Another *possible* pattern would be to use a flag so not listen the `CheckedChanged` event during you update the `checkbox` state by code.

```
private bool flagactivated = true;

private void myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //disable checkbox event
    flagactivated = false;

    //Do stuff
    //(...)

    //Activate event
    flagactivated = true;
}

private void mycheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (flagactivated) 
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an XY Problem, and you've got the problem statement down.

Adding a member bool feels hacky, but this should work for me.

Comment: @CPS You are probably right. I will remove it :) What I would like to note if that hooking the CellClick is probably not better. Off course you can also just detach the handler (-=) for CheckedChanged event to avoid to use a bool. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example showing the execution order of click events on a checkbox:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.MouseDown
    Dim a As Integer = 1
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Dim a As Integer = 2
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.Click
    Dim a As Integer = 3
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.MouseClick
    Dim a As Integer = 4
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.MouseUp
    Dim a As Integer = 5
End Sub
```

If you set breakpoints on each of the declarations, you will notice that only the MouseDown event is fired before CheckChanged. This means that if you want to see if a user clicked the checkbox, you would have to fire an event in the CheckBox.MouseDown sub. Be aware that any time a user clicks in this checkbox that it will fire this event, even if they drag the mouse out of it while holding it down which WON'T update the check changed event. This just means that you will have to fire a followup event in the MouseUp sub to clear the flag.

One way to handle it would be something like this:

```
Private blIsUserClick As Boolean

Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.MouseDown
    blIsUserClick = True
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If blIsUserClick Then
        'Is a user click event
    Else
        'Not a user click event
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.MouseUp
    blIsUserClick  = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This would not work if the checkboxes are changed using the keyboard (TAB to change the focus to a checkbox and SPACE to toggle it OR a keyboard shortcut - "&" in front of the ALT + shortcut letter in the text in the designer).